# gganimate returns group aesthetic warning

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I would like to create an animate graph using `gganimate`. The problem is that I keep getting the warning saying that each group consists of only one observation. To make it reproducible I'm using [this](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/gganimate-how-to-create-plots-with-beautiful-animation-in-r/) example which I can't even reproduce. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(gganimate)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
packageVersion("gganimate")
#> [1] '1.0.8'

p <- ggplot(
  airquality,
  aes(Day, Temp, group = Month, color = factor(Month))
) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  labs(x = "Day of Month", y = "Temperature") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")

p + transition_reveal(Day)
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see it doesn't even when running the same code from the example. So I was wondering if anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: The code works perfectly for me. I'm using the version 1.0.7. Maybe it is something related to the version that you are using. You can try installing a specific version or updating it to the latest version.

Comment: I confirm. On platform `"aarch64-apple-darwin20"` with `R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)` and `gganimate version 1.0.9` the warning is printed twice to the console.

Comment: I'm having the same results as @Friede. It is weird that it still returns these warnings.

Comment: I think the warnings are an unintended side effect of a [bug fix](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/409) in `transition_reveal` added in `gganimate 1.0.8` (i.e. you won't get any warnings in 1.0.7). This change already resulted in some other issues, see [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/473). While the plot seems to work you might still file an issue on the annoying warnings.